# mongoDB Indexing Failed

Tags: mongodb, indexing

So I had a mongoDB instance running for 4 hours (!) indexing a database of mine in various fields.

After the 4 hours had completed, and it reached 100% it gave me the following error:

`WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing  1085 { : "    8�o�E���E���E���F���E���F���F���H���H���F���G���G���H..." }`

This data was automatically gathered by scraping the web, so some unexpected results may show up. I am aware of the 1024 byte index key limitation of mongoDB. However! In the import code, I check for the top-max number of bytes that it allowed, like so:

```
BsonDocument CopyDoc = CurrentDoc;
foreach (void Fs_loopVariable in CurrentDoc("data").AsBsonDocument.ToList()) {
Fs = Fs_loopVariable;
if (System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetMaxByteCount(Fs.Value.AsString.Length) > 1000) {
    CopyDoc("data").Item(Fs.Name) = Fs.Value.AsString.Substring(0, 255);

    Console.WriteLine("Fixed something that was above 1024 bytes.");
    Console.WriteLine("Field: " + Fs.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Data: " + Fs.Value.AsString);
   }
}

json.Add(CopyDoc);
```

So theoretically, no entry should be above 1024 bytes, let alone 1000. If we find them, we truncate it to 255. Which is 256 - 1 (this string, even if entirely filled with Unicode characters, would still be under 1024 bytes).

What am I missing here?

Secondly, how can I get it to report the entry-too-long error immidiately, instead of having me sit through a 4 hour indexing build, that it *knows* is going to fail?

Comment: I still haven't figured it out, there's a falg that can be disabled to not error on this at all, isn't there just a way to either a) reject entries longer than 1024 bytes. b) figure out why my proposed solution is still giving me this error?

Comment: 1) Are you indexing all fields in a document? if so why? 2) If you're indexing text, have you considered using [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) instead ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not indexing all fields, that would ruin the point of the indexing. I have a rather large dataset consisting of a variety of different datapoints (auto-gathered by a script), but they have a few common-factors. I'm trying to index the text fields that are common amongst all data points (2 fields). However, this is proving harder than imagined. A text index wont work because I have 2 fields I need to index.